# ASP.NET Core MassTransit Azure Service Bus Request-Response with configuring Topic and Queue Name to handle MultiTenant case

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

Please can any one share code detail on MassTransit Configuration of Request and Respond ( Consumer ) project side so that both end we can distinctly specify these Topic/Queue/subscription "Name" string This allow us to segregate messages flow for each client in Multitenant application. I mean here, i want to use Single Application with Azure Service bus + MassTransit Request-Response cycle for multiple clients and each client should have their own Topic/queue/subscription .

At present i am using following code :

Request Client Side Masstransit Config :

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{    
    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(azureConnectionString); 
    });    
});
```

And Sending and Receiving request :

```
var client = _bus.CreateRequestClient<POOrderRequest>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
var response = await client.GetResponse<POOrderResponse>(poorder);
```

Consumer Side project :

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    { 
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
        
        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
        var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);            

            x.UsingAzureServiceBus(configure: (context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(connectionString: azureConnectionString);
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);                
            });            
        });        
    });
```

And Consumer Class :

```
public class InventoryConsumer : IConsumer<POOrderRequest> 
{        
    private readonly IPOOrderCreation _poOrder;
    public InventoryConsumer(IPOOrderCreation poOrder)  
    {
        _poOrder = poOrder;
    }
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<POOrderRequest> context)
    {   
        //Handler PO Creation and return response
        await context.RespondAsync<POOrderResponse>(await _poOrder.Create(context.Message));                    
    }
}
```